# How can I use one source file in node.js with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have one code in node.js.

```
var testFunc = function( y, m, d ) {
        //- do something~~
        return chkDObj.getFullYear( ) == y && chkDObj.getMonth( ) == m && chkDObj.getDate( ) == d;
};

res.render( "index.jade", { testFunc: testFunc } );
```

In jade,

```
script 
    var tmp = #{testFunc}
```

I want it to show same thing, but render result is,

```
<script>
var tmp = function( u, m, d ) {
        //- do something~~
        return chkDObj.getFullYear( ) == y &amp;&amp; chkDObj.getMonth( ) == m &amp;&amp; chkDObj.getDate( ) == d;
        };
</script>
```

How can I manage one source file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jade escapes all data by default. You can disable escaping by changing jour jade template:

```
script 
    var tmp = !{testFunc}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create js file like a utils.js, which is accessible through http and such as Node.js module. It's simple and works.